# Why do people sign their names with only their initials?

Tags: publications, personal-name

In my field at least, a lot of people sign their papers with just their initials. For example, the author list would be "J. Doe and S. Omeone". Why do people do this? It seems that it's just a recipe for creating homonyms-related problems. I can't see a reason to not include the full first name in the publication.

Comment: They do it because they choose to. If there are problems then they choose to ignore them. There is unlikely to be confusion if there is also an affiliation given.

Comment: At the time I started grad school, there was no other active author with my two initials and last name. Now, 35 years later, there is no other active author. My initials and last name seem to suffice.

Comment: A long time ago, well before the internet (for Amer. Math. Monthly problem solution submissions -- one being as early as 1974 although I think for this one my name appeared as D. Renfro, for letters to the editor of newspapers and science magazines, for a college newspaper science column I wrote in the mid 1980s, etc.), I decided to use "Dave L. Renfro", thinking that without the "L' it might not be sufficiently distinctive in years to come, but with "Lawrence" it would be a bit overdone, and I've kept it the same ever since. **(continued)**

Comment: In fact, for [one paper](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s00229-005-0604-z) I had to make a special appeal to the journal's editor to use my chosen name format.

Comment: I've more often seen this in a reference list than in actual author lists. In a reference list, it's partially a matter of pre-defined style, and besides nowadays including a DOI or other unique identifier is increasingly common. Anecdotaly, I also have a friend who's first name was the same as the name of the city he grew up in, say "Austin John West" from Austin, Texas (name made up for the example). He didn't like his first name, went by his middle name John with his friends and signed his work as "A. John West"

Comment: Could the answer have to do with printing costs / layout constraints of paper publications? Say a paper has 50 references, and each one has on average four authors, that's an extra 200 words - the size of an abstract

Comment: I have a lot of names that are very long

Comment: @Mowgli The OP seems to be referring to the authors' own names on the original manuscript. It's very common to abbreviate author names in citations for pragmatic reasons as you describe, but those reasons don't really apply when the author is writing their own name at the top of a manuscript.

Comment: @penelope No, I am talking about author list, the thing that is usually shown on the first page of an article. I am not talking about reference lists. Your example "A. John West" is not an example of signing only with your initials.

Comment: @Buffy My question is why they choose to do it, then... You're just eluding the question.

Comment: I don't think I fully understand what you mean by "just initials" then, as I find your example "J. Doe" (coming from John (first) Doe (last)) to be very similar to mine "A. John West" (Austin (first) John (middle) West (last)) name, as it is substituting the first name with an initial (rather than the middle as might be more conventional). Signing with "your initials only" would be signing as "J. D." (for John Doe) or as "A. J. W." (for "Austin John West") -- and I don't think that's acceptable practice anywhere I've seen. Could you be more precise in what you meant please?

Comment: @penelope I mean abbreviating everything but the last name.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. Haven't seen much (any) of that in my field (computer science) -- the standard is "First M. I. Last" (M. I. = Middle Initials, if any), so the example I gave above (A. John West) was quite unusual to me when I saw it (and coincidentally, the only time I saw somebody omit their _First_ name). Didn't realize there were some fields where it was frequent enough to merit a question :)

Comment: Go even further back, we find people used monoyms on their work (see https://hsm.stackexchange.com/a/11309/229 ) such as Tycho, Galileo, Leonardo, ...

Comment: Is there more than your impression that a lot of people do this kind of thing? Might be misleading. Actual data would help. And a lot of people can still be a minority. Can you clarify?

Answer (score 5):

There are many reasons not to include a full first name.

- You don't like or identify by your first name.
- The journal format demands it.
- You are trans-gender and have changed your first name, but not the initial or your surname.
- You are a minority in your field and hiding your first name means hiding clues to your minority status and possibly increasing the odds of your work being taken more seriously. (Mostly, hopefully, this reason is now outdated.)

Comment: This answer seems completely at odds with the fact that signing with only your initials is much more widespread than situations 3 and 4 actually occur. And while it might be plausible today, it wouldn't have been 30 years ago – and people still signed by their initials then.

Comment: @user118658 Really, #2 is the overriding reason for 99% of authors

Comment: @AzorAhai This does not match my experience. I have published in journals with my full name in the same issue as articles who only had the initials of the authors.

Comment: @user118658 My answer doesn't make claims about prevalence.  You said, "I can't see a reason to not include the full first name in the publication."  My answer gives you four.

Comment: @artificial_moonlet Yes, if you read this sentence literally without thinking about the context, then this would be an OK answer. But I'm really asking about an explanation for the general phenomenon, not an author's individual choice. If it were restricted to a minority of people, then the homonymy issue would be insignificant. Three of your answers are unsatisfying in that regard. The last one ("journal asked for it") is just eluding: why is the journal asking for it?

Comment: @user118658 Welcome to SE.  People are dicks and they're going to answer the literal question you ask.  Rewrite your question if your concern is why the journal is asking for such a naming format.

Comment: Except you didn't "answer the literal question [I] ask", you took one sentence an answered that without thinking about the rest. If you were writing a paper, it would get rejected for not seeing the obvious.

Comment: @user118658 Rewriting your question is the key to getting the answers you want.  Trust me.

Answer (score 3):

I suspect many contemporary authors use initials because it has become a long-standing tradition in academia. In other words, if it was good enough for A. Einstein, it is good enough for me.

[image: einstein]

Comment: This had attracted some flags / discussion, so I edited to try to make the relationship between the question and the answer clearer. Consider opening a post on [meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/) to discuss further, if needed.

Comment: Coupled with this, I think norms have simply changed over time regarding formality and the etiquette of using someone's first name. For example, I was taught to address a letter to "Dr A.B. Smith", but nowadays it seems that "Alice Smith" is more common.

Answer (score 3):

This is an example of a [social norm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Social_norm), which is a type of behavior that, once it becomes accepted by a group of people, perpetuates itself through group members’ tendency to adopt others’ behavior, perhaps out of a desire to not want to stick out or to be seen as unconventional.

So in my opinion, one good answer to “why do people sign their papers with just their initials?” is “because this is the norm in their field, which has developed because scholars of past generations adopted this practice.”

As for why this happened historically, it could have been a random event, or journals demanded it, or some famous scientists decided it was a good idea (e.g., to put the emphasis on the content of the research rather than the ego/personal brand of the author) and advocated for it, or some combination of the above.

By the way, social norms are all around us, so this idea answers many questions of the form “why do [members of group X] do [Y]?”, in particular in the context of academia.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure that was a valid reason 30 years ago, but it is somerimes difficult to determine where the first name stops and where the last name begins, especially when authors are from a different culture.

For example: in certain Asian cultures (e.g. in China) it is normal to write [one's family name *before* one's given name](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=http://www.nus.edu.sg/oam/docs/default-source/default-document-library/nameformatexplanationguide.pdf&ved=2ahUKEwjeoa2-wJfnAhWSTN8KHWmWD4EQFjAPegQICBAB&usg=AOvVaw2BuKw0oJbfL9qsB65ZyfrW). If you add "middle" names on top of that, things can get *very* confusing. If as a Westerner you're not familiar with common Asian last names, you might end up referring to a peer as "Dr. Firstname" instead of "Dr. Lastname".

It is also not uncommon for some names to be used as given and/or family names. A good example would be the name *Martin* in France: it is the most common last name... but it's also given as a first name. Consider literature Nobel prize laureate [Roger Martin du Gard](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://www.nobelprize.org/prizes/literature/1937/gard/biographical/&ved=2ahUKEwj6g_TzxJfnAhWBmuAKHRsfBRMQFjAVegQIAxAB&usg=AOvVaw2LQ41T6y7K8H4V7M3ux9yg): is Martin a middle name? The beginning of a double last name? Hard to tell if you don't know the author.

This type of issue pretty much disappears if one chooses to abbreviate given names and only write their last name.

Comment: There are also at least regions in "Western" Countries where it is not unheard of to address/refer to someone as Lastname Firstname, e.g. around the Alps I've met that in southern Germany and Italy, and I'd not be surprised at all to meet it in Austria (that is: I don't recall it, but I cannot say whether I met it and don't remember because it's inside what I expect there or whether I didn't hear it). In German German, it has a southern/Bavarian and old-fashioned and maybe rural/dialect connotation.

Answer (score 1):

One possible explanation is that people who reference papers tend to abbreviate authors' names even if they are given in full in the paper (to save place in the references section). Then when it comes to writing your own name as an author of the paper, they follow the same process out of habit without thinking much about it.

Answer (score 0):

I've never spent a conscious thought on this so far, but where I am for most business communication *F. Lastname* is just as common and acceptable as *Firstname Lastname* to address/refer to someone. In addition, *F. Lastname* (even if you have further given names) is acceptable and normal for most signatures.

However, looking though a bunch of papers, I do have the impression that this less the authors' choice than a style choice of the journal. (And some use both: full Firstname Lastname under the title and F. Lastname on the header of subsequent pages). At least for the last papers I submitted, the journal web page asked given and family name of all authors.

---

That being said, we frequently use *F. Lastname* for posters and presentations and their abstracts (possibly giving *Firstname* of the presenting authors so people have a chance to know how to address them): I'm often involved in rather interdisciplinary studies so there's frequently a whole bunch of authors that needs fit into a restricted space.

Answer (score 0):

Having used "A. R. Blass" on some of my earliest papers, I can explain one motivation. These were joint papers with my undergrad teacher Caslav Stanojevic who (like many Eastern Europeans, as far as I know) usually used only initials, "C. V. Stanojevic". I just matched that for the sake of uniformity. In my later papers, I used "Andreas Blass".

I might add, just as an example of the confusing things that can happen, that for the first eight years or so of my life, I was "Raphael Andreas Blass" but was called "Andreas" (or the diminutive "Anderl" because I was a little kid). When I became a naturalized U.S. citizen, this phenomenon of being called by my middle name so confused the officer from the Immigration and Naturalization Service that I had to become "Andreas Raphael Blass".

As long as I'm describing confusions: I've been told that Vietnamese names have the family name before the given name (as in Chinese and Hungarian), but in connection with titles (like Dr. or Prof.) one uses the last name, not the family name. Thus, for example, President Diem of South Vietnam was Ngo Dinh Diem; his brother, the archbishop of Hue, was Archbishop Thuc; his Vietnamese name was Ngo Dinh Thuc.